# How can i insert values from a list into a pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nan

i have this dataframe:

| index | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 0.07 | 4 |
| 2 | 0.1 | 6 |
| 3 | 0. 13 | 5 |

i want to insert new x values to the x column

`new_x = [0, 0.03, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13, 0.17, 0.2]`

so that the dataframe becomes

| index | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 0.03 | NaN |
| 2 | 0.07 | 4 |
| 3 | 0.1 | 6 |
| 4 | 0. 13 | 5 |
| 5 | 0. 17 | NaN |
| 6 | 0. 2 | NaN |

so basically for every `new_x` value that doesn't exist in `column x`, the `y value` is `NaN`

is it possible to do it in pandas? thank you

Comment: is `index` the index or is it a column?

Comment: hello, 'index' is an index, not a column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can use Numpy's `searchsorted`.

After you create a `new_y` array that is the same length as the `new_x` array.  You use `searchsorted` to identify where in the `new_y` array you need to drop the old `y` values.

```
new_y = np.full(len(new_x), np.nan, np.float64)
new_y[np.searchsorted(new_x, df.x)] = df.y

pd.DataFrame({'x': new_x, 'y': new_y})

      x    y
0  0.00  3.0
1  0.03  NaN
2  0.07  4.0
3  0.10  6.0
4  0.13  5.0
5  0.17  NaN
6  0.20  NaN
```

Comment: You do love searchsorted ;)

Comment: Sometimes you find a hammer and everything starts to look like a nail.

Answer (score 3):

This is a straightforward application of the `merge` function for pandas. More specifically a `left join`.

```py
import pandas as pd

x1 = [0, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13]
y1 = [3, 4, 6, 5]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x": x1, "y": y1})

print(df1)

x2 = [0, 0.03, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13, 0.17, 0.2]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x": x2})

print(df2)

df3 = df2.merge(df1, how="left", on="x")
print(df3)


      x  y
0  0.00  3
1  0.07  4
2  0.10  6
3  0.13  5

      x
0  0.00
1  0.03
2  0.07
3  0.10
4  0.13
5  0.17
6  0.20

      x    y
0  0.00  3.0
1  0.03  NaN
2  0.07  4.0
3  0.10  6.0
4  0.13  5.0
5  0.17  NaN
6  0.20  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method. Here is some sample code that you could refer

```
d1 = {'x': [0, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13], 'y': [3,4,6,5]}
d2 = {'x': [0, 0.03, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13, 0.17, 0.2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2.set_index('x').join(df1.set_index('x'), on='x', how='left').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this, you can compare the values already present in the column with the new one's and then you can create a df remaining values and concatenate it to the older df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,0.07,0.1,0.13], 'y':[3,4,6,5]})
new_list = [0, 0.03, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13, 0.17, 0.2]
def diff(new_list, col_list):
    if len(new_list) > len(df['x'].to_list()):
        diff_list = list(set(new_list) - set(df['x'].to_list()))
    else:
        diff_list = list(set(df['x'].to_list()) - set(new_list))
    return diff_list
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'x':diff(new_list,df['x'].to_list()),'y':np.nan})
fin_df = pd.concat([df,new_df]).reset_index(drop=True)
fin_df 
x   y
0   0.00    3.0
1   0.07    4.0
2   0.10    6.0
3   0.13    5.0
4   0.03    NaN
5   0.20    NaN
6   0.17    NaN
```